# Activate and inactivate modal popup in ng-bootstrap angular5

Tags: angular, html, ng-bootstrap

How can I activate(editable) and inactivate(not editable) an ng-bootstrap modal popup?

I am using the below html code to bring a modal popup on a button click. I need to pop it up and be inactive until I set a value to true.

But I don't know how to do the same. please help. Thanks in advance.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click to open</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">        
        <h4 class="modal-title"> Modal Box</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Click OK </p>
        <input [(ngModel)]="name"><br>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Boolean variable in the component named 'inactive' for example:

```
inactive: Boolean = true;
```

and then use the Angular [disabled] attribute in the inputs like this:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Click OK </p>
    <input [(ngModel)]="name"  [disabled]="inactive"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" [disabled]="inactive">Ok</button>
  </div>
```

By doing this, if you set the inactive variable to true, the modal popup fields will be inactive, else they wont.